# error[E0158] when testing default contract from flipper

Tags: ink, pallet-contracts

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/prepare-your-first-contract/

Hi, I'm working on the above tutorial and after running the `cargo +nightly test` command, I see the following error.

```rust
error[E0158]: associated consts cannot be referenced in patterns
  --> flipper/lib.rs:9:5
   |
9  | /     pub struct Flipper {
10 | |         value: bool,
11 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

Nothing has been changed from the source code here. What is a workaround for this please?

https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/examples/flipper/lib.rs

Comment: I just did git clone for ink repo and `cargo +nightly test` work just fine. What is your contract version? try `cargo contract -h`. mine is 1.3.0

Comment: I have the same problem. Mine is 1.5.0

Comment: While it does not fix your issue, you can use `cargo test` instead, it will work.

Comment: @Maario mine is also 1.5.0

Comment: @Cromm you are right, the tests do run correctly without the nightly channel

Comment: What about building it? I got the same error but couldn't build without the nightly channel

Comment: @marethyu same, build did not work

Comment: I don't seem to have the same error. Working on version 1.4.0. Maybe try downgrading?

Comment: @rạohs I do cargo install cargo-contract@1.3.0 --force and 1.4.0 but both build fails. @@

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**cargo-contract** latest release currently is **v1.5.0** which was released on **15th August 2022**.
So I used rust nightly build of that day and it worked. I have ran the following commands and I am able to build the contract.

```
rustup toolchain install nightly-2022-08-15
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-2022-08-15
rustup component add rust-src --toolchain nightly-2022-08-15
cargo +nightly-2022-08-15 contract build
```

Comment: Indeed this works, thanks! But that does not solve the issue, it shouldn't be needed to use the same specific release date ? Or does it ?

Comment: For me this solved the issue.

Comment: I use `cargo +nightly-2022-08-15 test` rather `cargo +nightly test` to test and `cargo +nightly-2022-08-15 contract build` to build rather `cargo +nightly contract build` today and it works for me. My `cargo contract version cargo-contract 1.5.0-unknown-x86_64-apple-darwin` and `rustc 1.66.0-nightly (c0983a9aa 2022-10-12))`