# compile smart contract error[E0158]

Tags: ink, smart-contract

ı'm trying to compile the smart contract with "cargo +nightly contract build" but it gives this error below. Everything is up to date. I can't seem to find the answer. Please help me on this matter.

```
Updating crates.io index
   Compiling flipper v0.1.0 (/private/var/folders/0n/pj5x0p_n66q348m2wdhdm3w00000gn/T/cargo-contract_43QsMb)
error[E0158]: associated consts cannot be referenced in patterns
  --> /Users/arifburakkorkmaz/flipper/lib.rs:8:5
   |
8  | /     /// Defines the storage of your contract.
9  | |     /// Add new fields to the below struct in order
10 | |     /// to add new static storage fields to your contract.
11 | |     #[ink(storage)]
...  |
14 | |         value: bool,
15 | |     }
   | |_____^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0158`.
error: could not compile `flipper` due to previous error
ERROR: `"/Users/arifburakkorkmaz/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo" "build" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "-Zbuild-std" "--no-default-features" "--release" "--target-dir=/Users/arifburakkorkmaz/flipper/target/ink" "--features=ink_env/ink-debug"` failed with exit code: Some(101)
```

Comment: This a known issue right now. An update of the nightly compiler has, unfortunately, broken the compilation process. This [question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4785/errore0158-when-testing-default-contract-from-flipper) contains the answer. And this [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1418) will fix the error.

Comment: I use `cargo +nightly-2022-08-15 test` rather `cargo +nightly test` to test and `cargo +nightly-2022-08-15 contract build` to build rather `cargo +nightly contract build` today and it works for me. My `cargo contract version cargo-contract 1.5.0-unknown-x86_64-apple-darwin` and `rustc 1.66.0-nightly (c0983a9aa 2022-10-12))`